# Is there a way to check if headers exist on a CSV in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv, parsing

I'm given a CSV that contains many rows. This CSV may or may not contain a header. E.g.

```
Column Name 1,Column Name 2
data1,data2
data3,data4
data5,data6
...
```

My goal is to extract the leftmost column into an array, which I can do by doing this

```
const column = csv
.split('\n')
.filter(r => r)
.map(r => r.split(',')[column]?.trim())
.slice(1);
```

This would return

```
['data1', 'data3', 'data5']
```

My issue is that this is assuming that the CSV has a header - I `slice(1)` the header out of the solution. If I were given a CSV without a header, I would accidentally omit the 0th row.

Is there a way to check if headers exist, or a better solution to this problem in general?

Comment: “*Is there a way to check if headers exist*” Do you have any discrete logic to determine whether a specific row of data represents header data? If so, why not just read the first row after the `map()` you’re doing and check if the row is a header before slicing it? `column[0].includes('expected-header-name')`?

Comment: Tangential, but you should also consider using a proper CSV parser for this as opposed to blindly splitting by new lines and commas, as there are a sufficient amount of edge cases where your current code would output some unexpected results.

Comment: @esqew the header names could be anything, so I'm unable to hardcode header names into it. 

Good tip about the parser, but would a CSV parser be able to differentiate headers vs other data?

Comment: CSV isn’t a particularly “smart” data format; it doesn’t intrinsically contain information about which rows represent header data. That would be on you as the designer/developer to implement some sort of mechanism to discern if the first row represents header data or not. My advice would be to study the data itself and come up with some characteristics of your headers on how exactly they differ from the data itself, then translate that data to JavaScript to make that determination in your code.